# Monitoring ETW logs on remote computer

Tags: c#, etw

The usage of **Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent** library makes it easy to work with **ETW** logs on `local machine` - but is there really a way to do the same for `remote server`? This is how do I get the events of interest on local machine. Really interested how would one achieve the same result in case of events being generated for different machine.

```
 public LoggingEventArgs ListenForEvent(string eventName, int level, int maxWaitTimeInSec = 30)
    {
        if (!(TraceEventSession.IsElevated() ?? false))
        {                
            _logger.Error("To turn on ETW events you need to be Administrator.");
            return null;
        }

        LoggingEventArgs result = null;

        _logger.Info("Creating a '{0}' session", _sessionName);
        using (var session = new TraceEventSession(_sessionName))
        {
            _timer = ConstructTimerForSession(session, maxWaitTimeInSec);

            TargetEventReceived += delegate (object sender, LoggingEventArgs e)
            {
                //if level is not negative, check for specific level of incoming event. 
                //Otherwise track all levels
                bool condition = level > 0 ? e.Level == level : true;                    
                if (condition)
                {
                    result = e;
                    StopListeningForEvents(session);
                }
            };

            AddCallbackForProviderEvent(session, _providerName, eventName);

            StartListeningForEvents(session, _providerName, _timer);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: run your cmdline tool via PsExec remotely: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't exactly what you are looking for but your best bet is to use the [Semantic Logging Application Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775014(v=pandp.20).aspx) (SLAB) out of process option which installs an agent on the remote machine. Then the SLAB process can write your logs to a remote SQL server or remote file.

Comment: Looks promising, thank you for pointing this option out! Will definitely give it a try, although I seem like giving up this idea of remote machine monitor at all - doesn't look like the 100% valid thing one would do - more like breaking the concept of eventing